# Which packages are included in FrameworkReference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I recently learned that you can add a `FrameworkReference` in a C# project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This allows you to use ASP specific APIs in class libraries, e.g., stuff from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.* assemblies like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`. This also allows you to use some of the Microsoft.Extensions.* assemblies, e.g., `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations`.

Can I use all Microsoft.Extensions.* packages in my class library after adding the `FrameworkReference`. If yes: Great! If no: Where can I find an overview?

I consulted the docs, but could not find any information at these places:

- The page [Runtime libraries overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/runtime-libraries-overview) basically says: "Some packages are part of the shared framework." However, it does not tell you which ones.
- The page [Use ASP.NET Core APIs in a class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) tells you about `FrameworkReference`. However, it does not say which packages are included and which ones are not.
- The page [.NET application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-framework-dependent) says that framework-dependent publishing has the advantage that deployments are small because some libs are included by the runtime. However, it does not say which ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could find them in your solution explorer:

[image]

Comment: Many stuff is usually contained in the documentation. What if I am not using Visual Studio?

Comment: Then the tool you use presumably still uses msbuild for this. FrameworkReference is a thing used by msbuild and less by Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi,@pschill,
dose this answer your question :https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/docs/SharedFramework.md#how-to-adjust-what-is-in-the-shared-framework